# German Umlauts in Apache

Tags: apache

I have a file with German umlaut in my filespace, and I am mapping directly to it through Apache HTTP server with the same filename in the URL.  So the file is ütest.jpg on the drive and the URL is [http://mysite/afolder/ütest.jpg](http://mysite/afolder/%C3%BCtest.jpg).  However, I get a 404 when I try to hit it in the browser.  Looking at the Apache logs I can see this is because the GET from the browser is somehow being converted...

[30/Jan/2017:13:52:09 +0000] "GET /afolder/%C3%BCbtest.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404

What am I missing here?  Both Apache and the filesystem seem to be set to use UTF-8, but I must be missing an Apache setting somewhere.

Comment: First of all, you should never neglect proper URL-encoding. When you just write `ü` in a URL in HTML, then it is up to the browser to decide what _character encoding_ to assume to get the actual bytes values necessary to apply the URL encoding you neglected. Secondly, the underlying file system might _not_ use UTF-8 - so even if your “Apache is set to it”, that might not mean that it and the file system can communicate properly in that regard. The best advice is probably the good & old one: _Avoid_ non-ASCII characters in URLs wherever possible.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I know that the filesystem is using UTF-8.  Unfortunately, avoiding the umlaut's is not an option in this case.  I've seen other Apache servers doing this so I know it is possible (and works with the browsers I'm testing with), but I'm clearly missing a key step.

Comment: `%C3%BC` would be the correct URL encoding for an `ü` in UTF-8. What do you get when you request `http://mysite/afolder/%FCtest.jpg` instead in your browser?

Comment: If I hit... http://mysite/afolder/%C3%BCtest.jpg then I still get a 404.  The browser changes the URL to display http://mysite/afolder/ütest.jpg.  If I hit http://mysite/afolder/%FCtest.jpg then I get a 404 but the URL in the browser does not change.

Comment: If neither the properly encoded UTF-8 nor the ASCII/ANSI version work … then it might still be a different encoding altogether. If you have PHP or something like that available, then you could try and read the directory contents using that, and look at the actual byte values used for the `ü`.